# Cascading MFB filters

Tags: active-filter

I am trying to create a 4th order active band-pass filter. I am using [this site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php), for calculations, as was once suggested by Andy aka.

I am able to get Q factor and center frequency just right for 2nd order MFB band-pass to achieve wanted filtering. However, I am unsure how to add the second stage to the first.

Will there be any loading effects by the second stage, should I just "copy/paste" the first stage? In general how would I choose the second stage resistors/capacitors, to get 4th order band-pass filter with -3dB at 20Hz and 200Hz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any loading effect caused by cascading the filter stages but the response won't be what you expect it to be.  The formula for calculating the filter components put the break point at the -3 dB point.  When you cascade the filters, the break point is now at -6 dB.

I had asked a similar question on this site and got a great response.  That question is at [tool-to-calculate-cascaded-but-independent-single-pole-rc-hi-pass-filters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156694/tool-to-calculate-cascaded-but-independent-single-pole-rc-hi-pass-filters)

You can use that question as a guide to coming up with the appropriate correction factor for your 2nd order filters.